# How to sort unique on a particular column and print the first unique 3 digit and add second column value

Tags: bash, awk

File.txt

```
chocolate,Paris,ER
milkchocolat,France,FR
berriesnoire,Paris,FR
chocolatewhite,Paris,FR
darkchocolat,Italy,IL
orange,usa,USA
plume,Paris,FR
milkshake,France,FR
orangebark,usa,USA
```

Desire Output:

```
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,paris

cat file.txt | awk -F”,” ‘{print $1”,”$2}’ | cut -c-3 | sort -u
```

This command It’s giving me only column one in the output

Current output:

```
ber
cho
dar
mil
ora
plu
```

Comment: Your code example is using "[smart quotes](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/smart-quotes-in-word-702fc92e-b723-4e3d-b2cc-71dedaf2f343)", make sure to use ANSI quote characters (`"` and `'`) in your real code instead.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed and sort:

```
sed -E 's/(...)[^,]*/\1/; s/,[^,]*$//' File.txt | sort -u
```

Output:

```
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,Paris
```

---

See: [5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)

Comment: It’s not printing second column; only the first one sorted as my awk command

Comment: Show output of `sed --version 2>&1 | head -n 1`

Answer (score 3):

For each line, associate the first three letter with the count of occurences of them in records in an array and use it to supress duplicates. Thus, print the first three letter and the second field of each unique record.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !seen[key=substr($1,1,3)]++{print key,$2}' file | sort
```

Given your sample input, output is as follows:

```
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,Paris
```

---

Or, with any sed and sort:

```
sed 's/\(...\)[^,]*\(,[^,]*\).*/\1\2/' file | sort -u
```

---

Note that the first one will list a record only if its first three letter is unique. However the second one will list a record if both the first three letter of first column and the entire second column is unique.

For an input like this:

```
chocolate,Paris
chocolate,paris
```

first one's output will be:

```
cho,Paris
```

but second one's output will be:

```
cho,Paris
cho,paris
```

Since you didn't clarify on that, I added solutions for both cases, use the one that meets your requirements.

Comment: Since he uses `sort -u`, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print substr($1,1,3),$2}' File.txt | sort -u` would also be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%.3s,%s\n", $1, $2}' data.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: You mean lowercase?

Comment: Can you please quote that from the OP?

Comment: The second column is a location. All of which were capitalized in the OP's sample. If the OP wants that behavior they can pass it through `tr`. I think you're nit-picking at minutiae.

Comment: Whatever. OP should have clarified that, it's not your or my fault

Comment: Cyrus's answer doesn't handle that either. I didn't see any objection to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple **awk** | **sort** solution:

```
$ time awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ print substr($1, 1, 3), $2 }' file | sort -u
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,Paris

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.006s
```

I thought it would be faster to save IO by doing the **-u** part in **awk**, but it's either equivalent or a bit slower:

```
$ time awk -F, -v OFS=, -v SUBSEP=, '
    BEGIN { split("", a) }
          { a[substr($1, 1, 3), $2] = "" }
    END   { for (i in a) print i }
' file | sort
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,Paris

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.004s
```

But it is a bit faster to ditch the pipe and do the whole thing in a version of **awk** that has an `asorti()` implementation:

```
$ time gawk -F, -v OFS=, -v SUBSEP=, '
    BEGIN { split("", a) }
          { a[substr($1, 1, 3), $2] = "" }
    END   { N = asorti(a); for (i=1; i<=N; ++i) print a[i] }
' file
ber,Paris
cho,Paris
dar,Italy
mil,France
ora,usa
plu,Paris

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
```

So, it's up to you... the first solution is the simplest and arguably the most flexible because if we want a slightly different implementation (like for instance sorting by the second column or changing the number of characters in the `substr()`) it's pretty straightforward to do because there is a good separation of concerns between the two tools in the pipeline.  However, if we are concerned about memory and speed, we probably want to think about the last solution.

Notes:

- For what it's worth, I compared **mawk** 1.3.3 and **gawk** 4.2.1 on the first two solutions, and **gawk** consistently beat **mawk** in **time** for these cases.)
- I also timed piping output to `/dev/null` the results of each implementation relative to each other were similar.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.